# Segmentation fault when creating two link lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, initialization, singly-linked-list

The below C++ code raises a segmentation fault error. When only one linked list is created and displayed everything works file. But after introducing the second list causes error.
Goal here is to create and display two linked lists.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int value;
    node* link;
};

void insert_into_list(node** head, int value) {
node* temp = new node;
temp->value = value;
temp->link = (*head);
(*head) = temp;

}
void display_link(node* he) {
cout << "Link List:\n";
node* head = he;
while (head != NULL) {
    cout << head->value;
    if (head->link != NULL)
        cout << "->";
        head = head->link;
}
cout << endl;
}

int main() {

    node* head1;
    node* sec;
    insert_into_list(&head1, 9);
insert_into_list(&head1, 7);
insert_into_list(&head1, 6);

display_link(head1);
cout<<"LKL"<<endl;


insert_into_list(&sec, 8);
insert_into_list(&sec, 6);
insert_into_list(&sec, 7);

display_link(sec);

}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour because variables

```
node* head1;
    node* sec;
```

were not initialized.

Use instead

```
node* head1 = 0;
node* sec = 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

It is a mystery it worked for `head1`.

You should give your list a proper ending.

```
node* head1 = 0;
```

You would also help yourself if you provided your `node` with a constructor, like

```
node(int value, node* next);
```